# Problems exporting PDF with dompdf using WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, dompdf

**Goal:** Export PDF successfully.

**Problem:** When the PDF is downloaded, I can't open it. If I open it with Chrome, I get the error "Failed to load PDF document" and if I open it in Firefix, it just sits there loading forever.

**Abouy my little script:** I'm trying to export a dummy content from the official dompdf demo example. I'm running this little script in a custom plugin and with a shortcode embedded in a page.

```
require_once('/myurl/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/dompdf/autoload.inc.php');
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
```

This code is from the [official documentation](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf).

I tried adding headers like this, but nothing:

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

I'm not even printing any PHP variable, just the phrase "hello world", I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I have been checking apache error logs file and I don't see any error or warning.

I'm wondering that maybe the problem is that is not possible export content to PDF using dompdf using WordPress and working with shortcodes, or I don't know.

Someone can help me?

**EDIT 1:** I tried to open the PDF with notepad and I see the document but like incomplete, instead of the whole code :

[image]

Maybe I'm having problems because dompdf has to read a lot of code from WordPress plugins and so on.

Comment: You can check what you're actually downloading with a plain text editor. What do you see?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I hadn't thought about it. I just opened it and I see the code for my page but not all the code, just the beginning, as if it stops at my head tag, as if it can't read any more. I took a screenshot: https://imgur.com/RvyBAPT

Comment: Well, now you know why the PDF is invalid. I can't be sure why this occurs, if could be something as simple as a 404 error: File Not Found.